# how to detect a text file whether is still opened by TextEdit

Tags: macos, file-io, process

Using lsof I can know a docx file is still opened by Word , but how to detect a text file (rtf, txt and so ) is still opened by TextEdit?

Comment: Are you writing a bash script?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Some context could help with getting you an answer.

Comment: I want to change the file just when it's closed. On windows, if this file is opened, you can not modify it, but on Mac, you can do this regardless of open or not. So I need to find a way to detect whether the file is still used by any process.

Comment: Very typical ETL use case.  It may take several minutes to complete a file transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x), you could try the following:

Commands:

- `sudo  lsof -V  | grep [filename]`
- This worked for me, but I had to do it *before* TextEdit opened it:

  `sudo  fs_usage | grep [filename]`

Apps:

- [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart)
- [Sloth](http://sveinbjorn.org/sloth)

After opening Sloth, it said this was open by TextEdit:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data
```

So one thing you could try is to see if TextEdit stores any data there:

- `sudo grep -R '[filename]' ~/"Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data"`
- `sudo grep -R [filename] ~/"Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Saved Application State"`

Comment: you are so cool, sudo lsof -V works for me , the only problem is it's using sudo, it's hard to call this command from objective c, but I can fix this, thanks buddy!

Comment: I'm surprised that worked for you! It didn't work for me; I had to use `fs_usage`

Comment: fs_usage doesn't work for me and when I use this command it never exits automatically. The result from sloth is just the same as lsof without sudo, from which you can not tell which file is opened. When I use sudo lsof -V I can see something like this "filecoord 238 ....aaa.rtf", if I closes the file, I got nothing, and this is what I want. Thanks

Comment: `fs_usage` never exits because it is constantly monitoring file access :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull up the file using `lsof -V` and `grep -A 5 TextEdit`. Then maybe you could use `pstree` to identify the parent process, and see if it's TextEdit. I would try to test a solution for you, but brew's servers seem down today (which is what I need to install it).

Comment: I tried this method, it doesn't work on my side:(, it seems we have no way to do this for TextEdit. I have tried many methods, scripts, c code and so on, I can get some results, but all of them are not the result I am expecting. For example, when we open a file with Work, we can use lsof to see that this file is still opened by "Microsoft Word", but for TextEdit, there are a lot of files are opened by Textedit (I feel these are some assistant files) except the files created by us.

Comment: I managed to use applescript to resolve txt files, but still can not fix rtf mode....