# Cocoa class to check which running apps are accessing disks

Tags: macos, cocoa, disk

I am working on a simple **Disk utility** type application. I would like to add a feature that lists which running application's are currently accessing a particular disk. I'm not really sure which Cocoa Class implements this.

Just to elaborate, the closest description of what I'm looking for is the **alert** that appears when trying to **unmount** a disk in use. The **alert** goes something like "Disk so and so can not eject because application so and so is using it." How do I check which applications are currently accessing a specific drive.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "XCode Class"? XCode is just an IDE.

Comment: You'll have to use the `FSEvents` API for this; watching the top-level directory of whatever filesystem you are interested in.

Comment: Corrected description... I meant Cocoa Class.

Comment: By "accessing" a disk, you mean have files open on a disk, so it's related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x).

Comment: @JWWalker yes it's related to that question. I know this can be done thru NSTask lsof +D but I'm wondering if there's a Cocoa class that already does it.