# Is there an alternative option to lsof for detecting open files for a process on macOS?

Tags: macos, process, filesystemwatcher, lsof

I need to be able to know all of the files a web browser has open (most specifically Google Chrome).

Right now I've only been able to find the results I need with `lsof` since this is a fairly low-level operating system request.  Basically I use `lsof` and then look through the list it returns and determine whether any files are downloading and then take some actions based on this result.

The problem I'm having is that `lsof` is a CPU pig even on a good day.  Sometimes I'm hitting a wall where `lsof` just goes nuts and `lsof` has to be killed manually.  I have to believe that Chrome does something funny as it seems as though it's the only misbehaved app that causing this trouble for `lsof`.

I'd love to have a better way of detecting download activity, but haven't been able to come up with anything that's reliable.

It seems as though Chrome has some sort of file handle open that `lsof` can't deal with or that causes it to suck down a serious amount of cpu time. (I'm wondering if  the problem could be a giant memory-mapped file that Chrome uses as its own private virtual memory system or something?)  Since this problem doesn't happen consistently I'm trying to hunt for `lsof` options for macOS that might behave a little better...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-accessing-a-file-in-mac-os-x